# Cloning directory without creating a new folder in with git

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

i want to know if there is any option to clone the content of a repository without creating a new folder in.

In my case i am trying to clone the same content in the same folder but with different users the problem appears when one new user try to clone the content for work with it in Visual Studio Code, it creates a new folder, example:

My repository names: Workarea
And when i clone it appears with the name Folder and its only 1, but when the new user want to clone it, git creates a new Folder with the name Workarea-1

Exist any option to just only clone the files without creating a new folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does not seem like a good idea to me to have two users working in the same directory. If there's already a clone there, why do you want a second clone in the same place, won't that just create file conflicts?

Comment: Because we dont want to get the same files taking too much space, they will use it 1 time upload the content and stop working but we need a place for work, so we cant create like 400 folders anytime we want to work

Comment: @jurez No, i already try it but doesn't work for me